# NodeJS and mongodb caching

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have MongoDB database installed in USA server 
and we are deploying 5 API servers in following locations
1) USA
2) UK
3) Australia
4) Brazil
5) Japan

These are all the 5 servers will be  querying the MongoDB server in USA.
Which will be best caching technology(installed in the API server) to cache the api calls ?

Comment: Are you using indexes? have you thought about a MongoDB replica set with different regions (like AWS)?

Comment: We are looking for a solution , currently we are not using anything. 
We considering making MongoDB replica set with setting priority 0 , but hosting those huge database servers in different places will be very costly for us. So we are looking forward to keep the database in only a data center.

Comment: use redis or memcache

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use one of the solution that I have built. What it does is it creates the in memory caching for all the mongodb find operations and you don't have to refactor the code, you can run it alongside the application as well. Since it is written in Rust it is highly memory efficient. [Rengo](https://github.com/sanket2904/rengo)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).